# React useState overwrites state object instead of merging

Tags: reactjs

Instead of merging changes I make to a state object, React is overwriting it completely.

Could this be caused by the context? I'm not sure if I can pass a dispatch event directly as a prop. I've tried wrapping `setParams` in another function, like in the ["lifting state up" docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), however to no effect.

**Expected Output**

```json
{width: 400, height: 400, strokeWeight: 0.25, color: "#d9eb37", resolution: 10}
```

**Current Output**

```json
{color: "#d9eb37"}
```

**React context holds the state**

```js
const Context = createContext();

const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [params, setParams] = useState({
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    strokeWeight: 0.25,
    color: "#ad3e00",
    resolution: 10
  });

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ params, setParams }}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

**Generic input component**

```js
const Input = () => {
  const { params, setParams } = useContext(Context);

  render(
    <input
        type="color"
        value={params.color}
        onChange={(e) => setParams({ color: e.target.value })}
      />
  );
}
```

Comment: That's how `useState` works. It replaces the value, it does not do any merging. That's on you to do

Comment: I'd recommend using the [functional update form](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) of `setParams` for setting state (mentioned only in comments and non-accepted answers on the linked question above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useState` does not merge state like `setState` in class component, you have to do the job on your own.

`onChange={(e) => setParams((params)=>({ ...params, color: e.target.value }))}`